# LaTeX moderncv casual: Change the width of the extrainfo

Tags: moderncv

I want to limit width of the \extrainfo field, where I want place some long text. How can I do such thing? Now it looks like this:

[image]

I am using moderncv with casual blue style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch `\makecvfooter` so that `\@extrainfo` is placed inside a `\parbox` of the desired width and with the desired formatting; for example, using `\linewidth` for the width and `\centering` to have the information centered:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvfooter}
  {\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}
  {\addtofooter{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\@extrainfo}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{The title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information and some other text goes here and we add some more text for the example}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update:

After the comment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvfooter}
  {\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}
  {\addtofooter{\makebox[\linewidth]{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\@extrainfo}}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{The title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information and some other text goes here and we add some more text for the example; here we add osme additional text}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's almost great. One more question, how can I move this element to the left. I want fill total size of page? (with margins of course).